# Woocommerce - Cart Page - Change Sequence of Products in Cart (Travel Packages)

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I am trying to sell self-built travel packages with woocommerce. So a visitor would choose a number of their preferred hotels, activities, and transport, then add them into the shopping cart.

The problem I am facing is that items (travel products) are added into the shopping cart in the sequence that they were added.

However, I would need the function that like this:  either the admin or guest will be able to re-arrange the positions (sequence) these items appear in the cart. Maybe like a AJAX drag and drop function would be great.

Is there a way to do so?

Ps. I am not refering to changing the order products appear in catalog, that's easy with plugins.

Please give me some direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I once considered re-ordering the items in the cart from my plugin, but ultimately decided it wasn't worth it for me. Here's what I was going to use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'so_26640996_reorder_cart_keys' );

/**
 * Re-order the cart keys to keep container/bundled items from being separated in case of force-sells
 * @param  object   $cart - the WC_Cart class
 * @return void
 */
function so_26640996_reorder_cart_keys( $cart ){

    if( $cart->cart_contents ) { 

        $new = array();

        $contents = $cart->cart_contents;

        // loop through the cart's contents
        foreach( $cart->cart_contents as $cart_key => $cart_item ){

            // add the item back into a new array of cart contents
            $new[$cart_key]=$cart_item;

            // if the cart item meets some condition re-arrange its position
            if( isset( $cart_item['mnm_contents'] ) && is_array( $cart_item['mnm_contents'] ) ){
                foreach($cart_item['mnm_contents'] as $key){
                    if( isset( $contents[$key] ) ){
                        $new[$key] = $contents[$key];
                        unset($contents[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        $cart->cart_contents = $new;

    }

}
```

It doesn't exactly fit your question (and is also very late) but maybe it will help someone with the same question.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.  Do you paste this code into the cart page?

Comment: No, ideally create a new plugin for it. Or at worst, try it in your theme's `functions.php`. Remember, this is just an example and probably won't do exactly what you were asking.

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking 
Your solution solved my problem, but some of your code I don't get it, appreciate if you could have the explanation.
In first loop `$new` already assigned for cart_item, but how `$new` in second loop can make the cart items in correct sequences?
And why `unset` needed, no matter apply `unset` or not, my sequences is correct.

Comment: @YingRuiWong because my 5 year old code is sloppy? I think you are right... there should not be a need to `unset()` anything and the `$contents` variable can probably be ignored. Though note I am referencing potentially using it in one of my plugins and perhaps only applying the sort to the product type created by my plugin.